# compiling source files in different directory

Tags: windows, makefile, driver, directory-structure

I am trying to compile source files from one level up from folder where my source and makefile is present. following is the my directory structure and I have implemented source file..

**Directory structure..**

project \common\a.c

```
     \platform\win\source
                 \makefile
```

Since my source file and make file, both are in win folder so I am trying to compile a.c from win folder

c:\project\platform\win\build -Cez

**SOURCE FILE**:

DIR=..\ ..\common

SOURCE= \
        $(DIR)\a.c

I am getting error "Invalid directory". Can any body suggest me what I am doing wrong or give any clue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the command you are using to compile?

Comment: I am using command "build -Cez"

Comment: The \ before `$(DIR)` should go.